# How to use `pre` in route handler - hapi.js

Tags: node.js, routes, hapi.js

I have to call a method using pre in a route. I am using [hapi-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-request). I tried to use pre in the route declaration, but I got an error. What am I missing?

**My original route:**

```
server.route({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    path: '/searchUser',  
    config: User.searchUser
})
```

**Using Pre**

```
server.route({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    path: '/searchUser',  
    pre: validateUser, 
    config: User.searchUser
})
```

**Error**

```
Error: Invalid route options (/searchUser) {
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/searchUser",
  "config": {}
}
←[31m
[1] "pre" is not allowed←[0m
```

Comment: what does `validateUser` look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pre` should be used inside the config object.

From the [route-prerequisites](https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionspre) documentation in Hapi:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    config: {
        pre: [
            [
                // m1 and m2 executed in parallel
                { method: pre1, assign: 'm1' },
                { method: pre2, assign: 'm2' }
            ],
            { method: pre3, assign: 'm3' },
        ],
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            return reply(request.pre.m3 + '\n');
        }
    }
});
```

**Updated Route:**

```
server.route({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    path: '/searchUser', 
    config: {
        handler: User.searchUser, 
        pre: [{ method: validate /* function to be called */ }]
    }
);
```

Comment: I dont see how this is very different from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The property pre of a route configuration object is not a function ([here](http://hapijs.com/api#route-configuration)) it is an array of object [route-prerequisites](http://hapijs.com/api#route-prerequisites)

Comment: You should precise this in your question it will help people to answer. :)

Comment: ok. Even I tried array of object but I got error as `Error: Invalid route options (/test) {
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/test",
  "pre" ←[31m[1]←[0m: [
    {}
  ]
}
←[31m
[1] "pre" is not allowed←[0m`